# How Would You Explain React Context to a child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have been trying to wrap my head around React context for a while now, but I can't seem to understand any of it.

I understand its importance as it helps us solve the issue of props drilling, but the implementation in code is just so confusing to me.

I have questions like:

1. Am I suppose to create a new context for each state or have all the state in a single context?
2. What does useReducer do?
3. What is the diference between a Provider and a Consumer?
4. How do you update state in a store?
5. And many more.

This has been a problem for me and I have been stuck here for one week. I honestly feel like giving up on learning this stuff.

I have followed tons of tutorials on YouTube and read many articles, but it's not just clicking.

Please I would appreciate answers in simple English. Thank you!

Comment: Have you seen [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)?  It says *"Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass properties down manually at every level."*

Comment: It also says *"Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components, such as the current authenticated user, theme, or preferred language."* and *"Context is primarily used when some data needs to be accessible by many components at different nesting levels. Apply it sparingly because it makes component reuse more difficult."*

Comment: Is your question about react context or react-redux? Because as far as I know, you don't need useReducer, store in a simple react context. Those are concepts from redux.